# Raku: Using topic variable (from a 'for') inside a regex

Tags: regex, for-loop, raku, rakudo

I have this code that works as expected:

```
my @words = 'foo', 'bar';
my $text = 'barfoo';

for @words -> $to-regex {
    $text ~~ m/ ($to-regex) {say "matched $0"}/;
}
```

It prints:

```
matched foo
matched bar
```

However, if I try to use topic variable on the for loop, as in:

```
for @words { # implicit "-> $_", AFAIK
    $text ~~ m/ ($_) {say "matched $0"}/;
}
```

I get this:

```
matched barfoo
matched barfoo
```

Same results using postfix for:

```
$text ~~ m/ ($_) {say "matched $0"}/ for @words; # implicit "-> $_", AFAIK
```

Is this a special case of the topic variable inside a regex?

Is it supposed to hold the whole string it is matching against?

Comment: Note that regexes in raku are dreadfully slow and if you can avoid them you should. Here for instance, if one is just looking for presence of a substr in a str, using the index method is worth considering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smart-match operator has 3 stages

1. alias the left argument temporarily to `$_`
2. run the expression on the right
3. call `.ACCEPTS($_)` on that result

So it isn't a special case for a regex, it is how `~~` always works.

```raku
for 1,2,3 {
    $_.print;
    'abc' ~~ $_.say
}
# 1abc
# 2abc
# 3abc
```